# Mensagem de alerta

Tags: javascript

Estou usando o alert comum do javascript em uma função de verificação de campos:

```
if(document.cadFinan.dataParcel.value == ""){
    alert("O Campo data é obrigatório!");
    return false;
}
```

Mas gostaria de algo mais agradável, alguma caixa de texto personalizada para mostrar a mensagem.

Comment: Da uma olhada em bootstrap. É bem bacana e facil demais de implantar.

Comment: Segue uma lista com 10 http://www.sitepoint.com/10-jquery-alert-windows-prompts/ Só escolher e utilizar, caso nao ache nenhum que goste entre os 10, tem mais 40 aqui. http://jquery-plugins.net/tag/alert-box

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você poderia usar jQuery com algum plugin, como por exemplo estou usando o plugin jquery.modal.js:, mas existe muitos plugins disponível na internet, e só pesquisar por plugin model jquery.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</style>
  <script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
  <script src="jquery.modal.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
</head>
<body>

  <div id="ex1" style="display:none;">
    <p>Thanks for clicking.  That felt good.  <a href="#" rel="modal:close">Close</a> or press ESC</p>
  </div>

  <p><a href="#ex1" rel="modal:open">Open Modal</a></p>

</body>
</html>
```

Esse exemplo peguei do próprio site do plugin:
http://kylefox.ca/jquery-modal/examples/